# barcode scanner intent launches but cannot scan qr code?

Tags: android-intent, zxing

I am playing around with ZXing.  I have barcode scanner installed on my android phone and verified it can scan a qr code.  I then used this code I found in another SO post:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ALT+ENTER
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");//for Qr code, its "QR_CODE_MODE" instead of "PRODUCT_MODE"
    intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", true);//this stops saving ur barcode in barcode scanner app's history
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"); //this is the result
        } else
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
```

The intent launches from my app but it cannot scan that same qr code!  I added this permission in my manifest(neglecting tags for SO visibility):

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
```

and ran the app again, but it still cannot scan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in your own comments. You are asking it to only scan for product formats and not QR codes.

Comment: sorry, I thought of other possibilities and didn't scrutinize the code.